# MySQL SUM, ORDER BY, etc

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:
[image: Table]

What I need:
SUM(v+t+p) if m = '7' and SUM(v+t+p) if m = '8', and order it (by subtract (SUM(v+t+p) if m = '8')-SUM(v+t+p) if m = '7').

Comment: sounds well described luc.

Comment: What is the GROUPing criteria? Without one, there is no point to ORDERing.

Comment: what @Uueerdo is saying (I believe), is that you are using aggregate function sum(x), so do you mean addition v+t+p, as opposed to a sql group by ?

Comment: said another way, what are your expected results from your 5 rows above. Let's start there :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general form of what you are looking for (probably):

```
SELECT [somestuff?] 
, SUM(IF([condition1], [calculation1], 0) AS X1
, SUM(IF([condition2], [calculation2], 0) AS X2
FROM theTable
WHERE [something]
GROUP BY [something else]
ORDER BY X1 - X2
;
```

Several sections are possibly optional for you.

To be more specific...

```
SELECT SUM(IF(m = '8', v+t+p, 0) AS sum8
, SUM(IF(m = '7', v+t+p, 0) AS sum7
FROM theTable
ORDER BY sum8-sum7  // This ORDER BY won't really do anything; 
                    // there is only one row since we didn't 
                    // GROUP BY anything
;
```

Edit:
(for your back pocket to save some time, hopefully something useful)

```
create table thing
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    n int not null,
    m int not null,
    v int not null,
    t int not null,
    p int not null
);

insert thing(n,m,v,t,p) values (2,8,0,0,0);
insert thing(n,m,v,t,p) values (14,8,0,0,0);
insert thing(n,m,v,t,p) values (48,7,123,123,123);
insert thing(n,m,v,t,p) values (48,8,12,1,2);
insert thing(n,m,v,t,p) values (390,8,0,0,0);
```

Edit:

```
SELECT n
, SUM(IF(m = '8', v+t+p, 0) AS sum8
, SUM(IF(m = '7', v+t+p, 0) AS sum7
, SUM(IF(m = '8', v+t+p, 0)
  - SUM(IF(m = '7', v+t+p, 0) AS sumDiff
FROM the_table
GROUP BY n
ORDER BY sumDiff
;
```

Comment: greetings Uueerdo, can I do an edit at the bottom of yours so you can finish it off when OP comes back ?

Comment: @Drew Haha, you getting to know my hours? Sure, I don't mind.

Comment: so, now I have this:
SELECT n, m, v, t, p FROM table ORDER BY (SUM(IF(m = '8', v+t+p, 0))-(SUM(IF(m = '7', v+t+p, 0))))
(When I had SUM(IF...) AS SOME and ORDER BY SOME, it returned an error.)
As first it should return n '48' with value '-354', but it doesn't. It returns some bullshit.

Comment: @lucAss See last edit I made, after the `inserts` Drew added.